# Element jumps when using transform and transition property in CSS

Tags: html, css

Code below:

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 100px 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

p:active {
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<p>Sheeeet</p>
```

So things went as expected when I clicked on this element, but when I released the mouse the element jumped to another position as if there was no `transform-origin` in effect. Can this be fixed?

Comment: was wondering what `transform-origin` you need? since you have used `top left` in the `active` element, which is behaving as expected.

Comment: Works fine without `transform-origin` - Can not see an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ways of solving this:

> 1. Add `transform-origin:top left` in the `p` tag.

> OR

> 2. Remove `transform-origin:top left` in the `active` class.

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 100px 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform-origin: top left;
}

p:active {
  transform-origin: top left;
  transform: scale(2);
}
```

```html
<p>Sheeeet</p>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. But how could anyone figure it out in the first place?

Comment: When you're playing around with `hover` and `active` you should make sure to validate the difference between actual element and `active` or `hover`, so in your case it clearly showed that you're missing those properties.